# $R$ commutative ring having a non-zero nilpotent, then $R^{\times}\subsetneq (R[X])^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Also there is $a\in R$, $a\ne 0$, such that $a^n=0$. Then $R^{\times}\subsetneq(R[X])^{\times}$, so there is an element in $(R[X])^{\times}$ which is not contained in $R^{\times}$

I am struggling in finding such an element in $(R[X])^{\times}$ which is not contained in $R^{\times}$.

Any **tips?** Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider $1+ax$. More generally see Chapter 1 Exercises 1-2 of *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and Macdonald .

Comment: It is a little bit easier to consider $1-ax$.

Comment: When I first did this problem, I used the difference of squares rule instead of the identity in the other answer. You can also do it by inducting on the degree of nilpotence as $(1+ax)(1-ax)=1-a^2x$ and $a^2$ is strictly less nilpotent then $a$ as long as $a\ne 0$.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: If you just want a hint only read the next two lines.

Consider the general identity

$$A^n - B^n = (A-B)(A^{n-1}+ A ^{n-2}B + ...+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1})$$

which holds in any commutative algebra. Now let $A=1$ and $B=aX$, where $a^n = 0$ in $R$. Since $(aX)^n = a^n X^n = 0$, we have

$$ 1 = 1-0 = 1^n - (aX)^n = (1-aX)(1+aX+a^2X^2+...+a^{n-1}X^{n-1}).$$

This shows $1-aX \in R[X]^\times$, so $R[X]^\times$ has elements that are not in $R^\times$.